# Is the southern downwelling situation in the AMOC as affected by climate change as the two northern downwelling situations?

Tags: oceanography, thermohaline-circulation

I wonder if the southern downwelling situation in the AMOC is affected by climate change as much as the two northern situations. I come to the question because I find the Cicrumantarctic circulation climatically isolates this region and I have read in various papers like: Interbasin and interhemispheric impacts of a collapsed Atlantic Overturning Circulation that the northern downwelling situations are failing due to climate change.

[image]

Source: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermohaline_Zirkulation#/media/Datei:Thermohaline_Circulation.svg

In the figure that shows a simplified situation of the AMOC, the three downwelling situations I am talking about are clearly visible